# Python automatic indentation

Tags: python, editor

Suppose I have Python code like the following:

```
import sys #just an example

a=10
....
# a lot of lines here
....
print(result)
```

Suppose I want to wrap the many lines of code between `a=10` and `print(result)` in a function, how do I make sure the code is properly and automatically indented (especially for nested for-loops) when the code is pasted inside the function?

Can anyone show the way to do it in editors such as Emacs, vim, Sublimetext, etc.?

Comment: Is the code properly indented to begin with, in relation to the place you're taking it from? That is, do you need to actually check every line separately, or is it enough to increase the indent level by one?

If all you want is to increase the indent level by one on every line, in vim you could just visually select them and `>`. If you're going to be yanking/pasting those lines somewhere else, you'll need to select them for that anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some code that is formatted properly and pasted, you can move the code out in Emacs using `C-c <` (`python-indent-shift-left`) and push the code in deeper using `C-c >` (`python-indent-shift-right`).

In your case, just put a `def` header above the lines you're interested in, then mark the lines and hit `C-c >`.

Answer (score 2):

If the code is properly formatted and you want to wrap it inside a function you can always just select the code and hit <kbd>tab</kbd> than insert `def someFunction():` a before the code and you are done.

If you are using sublime text first you should hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> then type `convert to spaces`, hit <kbd>enter</kbd> and do what I wrote before this way you won't have tabs and spaces mixed. The reason I said space is because according to PEP8 style guide space is preferred over tabs.

Answer (score 0):

In Sublimetext2 you have it in Edit > Line > Reindent

Comment: This does not always work... Edit->Pase and Indent is much better. (just discovered this... I'm new to sublime)

Answer (score 0):

IdleX has methods indent/dedent under the tab format. Very important expansion to the standard Editor.